# Does every Star Wars episode really have at least 2 sunsets?

Tags: star-wars, the-simpsons

In the new *The Simpsons* short, *Maggie Simpson in "The Force Awakens From Its Nap"*, we get a look at some jokey "Star Wars Rules", see below:

> STAR WARS RULES
>
> 1) Beloved characters never really die.
> 2) No handrails.
> 3) Droids do not need to be plugged in.
> 4) Every episode must have at least 2 sunsets.

[image: The Star Wars Rules mimicking the SW opening crawl, quoted above]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Now from that list 1 is pretty obvious; if a main character dies then we'll probably see them somewhere else, i.e. Force ghost or not really dead in the first place. 2 and 3 are pretty common jokes about the series so we can ignore them. However, number 4 caught my interest for a bit of trivia.

**Does every episode of *Star Wars* really have at least 2 sunsets?** It seems plausible but at the same time I can't remember some of the Original Trilogy having that many or maybe Episode IX.

Comment: All four are demonstrably incorrect. Luke plugs Artoo into a power generator in ESB, for example,  there are oodles of examples of safety railings, etc https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWpj6.png

Comment: @Valorum The first 3 are pretty common jokes, even if untrue. 4 works along similar lines, being a joke, but one I haven't heard before.

Comment: No main character from Rogue One survives - beloved or not.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - That we know of.....

Comment: Hmm. From looking at the first six films in the series, it would appear that there's an average of one sunset per film, but several scenes set at dusk. They seem to like to mix up day scenes with night scenes too,

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - true, from a certain point of view. They are currently in production of "Andor" - a prequel series on Disney+ following Cassian Andor and eventually K2-SO, so from a certain point of view, they will remain active characters ;)

Comment: LOL.. I can't stop laughing!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Across the nine main Star Wars films, there are a total of fourteen sunsets, representing an average of ***just slightly over 1.5 SsPF (Sunsets Per Film)***.

Taking into account the other canon films (Clone Wars, Solo, Rogue One), that number declines to 1.33 SsPF.

---

### Star Wars 1: The Phantom Menace.

This film features a single sunset on Coruscant. There are also scenes at dusk on Naboo, but no suns are visible.

**Sunset on Coruscant**
[image]

---

### Star Wars 2: Attack of the Clones.

The film features several scenes set at dusk on Theed and Geonosis, and two sunsets, one on Tatooine and one on Coruscant.

**Sunsets on Tatooine**
[image]

**Sunset on Coruscant**
[image]

---

### Star Wars 3: Revenge of the Sith.

This film features three sunsets on Coruscant and Tatooine. There's also a dusk scene on Alderaan, but no sun is visible.

**Sunset on Coruscant**
[image]

**Sunset on Coruscant (a few days later)**
[image]

**Sunsets on Tatooine**
[image]

---

### Star Wars 4: A New Hope.

This film features a single sunset scene on Tatooine. We also see a dusk scene on Tatooine, but no suns are visible.

**Sunsets on Tatooine**
[image]

---

### Star Wars 5: The Empire Strikes Back.

This film features a single sunset on Bespin. Much of the action at the end of the film takes place at dusk on Bespin the following evening, but no suns are visible

**Sunset on Bespin**
[image]

---

### Star Wars 6: The Return of the Jedi.

This film features a single brief sunset on Tatooine. There are also scenes at dusk on Bespin and Yavin 4, but no suns are visible.

**Sunset on Tatooine**
[image]

---

### Star Wars 7: The Force Awakens

This film features a single sunset on Jakku.

**Sunset on Jakku**
[image]

---

### Star Wars 8: The Last Jedi

This film features sunsets on Canto Bight and Ahch-To.

**Sunset on Canto Bight**
[image]

**Sunset on Ahch-To**
[image]

**Sunsets on Ahch-To (the next day)**
[image]

---

### Star Wars 9: The Rise of Skywalker

This film features a single sunset on Bespin.

**Sunset on Bespin**
[image]

---

### Rogue One: A Star Wars Story

This film features no sunsets at all.

### Solo: A Star Wars Story

This film features a single sunset on Vandor-1

**Sunset on Vandor-1**
[image]

### Star Wars: The Clone Wars

This film featured a single sunset on Tatooine. The entire film is set almost exclusively at dusk on a wide range of planets, but no sunsets are seen elsewhere.

**Sunset on Tatooine**
[image]

Comment: (not sure if willfully ignoring E7-9 or just haven't gotten around to it yet...)

Comment: @NKCampbell He seems to have pulled his FGitW and keeps updating it in segments.

Comment: @Skooba - The first part of my answer (e.g. in the first film, there's only one sunset) answered the question entirely. Everything after that is me merely mucking around.

Comment: If we see two suns setting at once on Tatooine, does that count as two sunsets?

Comment: @MattGutting - Asking the big questions here. I'm gonna say *maybe*.

Comment: I gotta ask; on Tatooine would it be "sunsets" or "sunsset"?

Comment: @DavidW - I went with sunsets (singular).